# Invalid JSON Response in Datatables

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I'm modifying the `jQuery Datatables`. All I want is to add `datepicker` for searching two dates but I got an error response, it says invalid `JSON`. Below is my code:

```
    $column = array('reciept_no','username','firstname','lastname','TotalQuantity','TotalPrice','date');

    $query = "SELECT sales_product.reciept_no,sum(price) AS TotalPrice,sum(qty) AS TotalQuantity,username,date,customer.firstname,customer.lastname FROM sales_product JOIN sales ON sales_product.reciept_no=sales.reciept_no JOIN customer ON sales.customer_id = customer.customer_id GROUP BY reciept_no ";

    if($_POST['is_date_search'] == "yes"){
        $query .= 'HAVING sales.date BETWEEN "'.$_POST["start_date"].'" AND "'.$_POST["end_date"].'"'; 
    }

    if (isset($_POST["search"]["value"])) {
        $query .= '
            ( AND reciept_no LIKE "%' .$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
            OR TotalPrice LIKE "%' .$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
            OR TotalQuantity LIKE "%' .$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
            OR username LIKE "%' .$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
            OR firstname LIKE "%' .$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
            OR lastname LIKE "%' .$_POST["search"]["value"]. '%")
        ';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['order'])){
        $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
    }else{
        $query .= 'ORDER BY reciept_no DESC';
    }

    $query1 = '';

    if($_POST['length'] != -1){
        $query1 = 'LIMIT' .$_POST["start"].','.$_POST["length"];
    }
    $data = array();

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query . $query1);
    $number_filter_row = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($db, $query));

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $sub_array = array();
            $sub_array[] = $row["reciept_no"];
            $sub_array[] = $row["username"];
            $sub_array[] = $row["firstname"];
            $sub_array[] = $row['lastname'];
            $sub_array[] = $row["TotalQuantity"];
            $sub_array[] = $row["TotalPrice"];
            $sub_array[] = $row["date"];
            $data[] = $sub_array; 
        }
function get_all_data($db){
        $query = "SELECT sales_product.reciept_no,sum(price) AS TotalPrice,sum(qty) AS TotalQuantity,username,date,customer.firstname,customer.lastname FROM sales_product JOIN sales ON sales_product.reciept_no=sales.reciept_no JOIN customer ON sales.customer_id = customer.customer_id GROUP BY reciept_no";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        return mysqli_num_rows($result);
    }
    $output = array(
        "draw"      => intval($_POST["draw"]),
        "recordsTotal"  => get_all_data($db),
        "recordsFiltered" => $number_filter_row,
        "data"      => $data
    );

    echo json_encode($output);
```

The error says

> DataTables warning: table id=sales_table - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

I am referring to this site for my code and I'm just modifying it of what my systems need:
https://www.webslesson.info/2017/06/date-range-search-in-datatables-using-php-ajax.html

I did search the problem, and found out that it will be fetch on developer tools and clicking on the network tab. I found this one

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PointOfSale/sales/fetch_all_data.php on line 38
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PointOfSale/sales/fetch_all_data.php on line 40
> {"draw":1,"recordsTotal":10,"recordsFiltered":null,"data":[]}

I'd tried fixing my query but nothing happens.This type of query is new to me so its hard for me to site the problem. Can someone give me an idea or site what my code is lacking?

Comment: where is json in above code?

Comment: I'll update it.

Comment: u need to add alias here also `GROUP BY reciept_no`

Comment: I found that my query has a problem. I dont know whats problem in there cause I think its okay.

Comment: second, in this method `get_all_data` u just need count, so why are u selecting column names?

Comment: u r getting `NULL` against this `$number_filter_row`

Comment: I'm just referring to this tutorial, [link](https://www.webslesson.info/2017/06/date-range-search-in-datatables-using-php-ajax.html)

Comment: add table alias here `GROUP BY reciept_no`

Comment: where I can put that? on the while ?

Comment: `echo $query . $query1;` please share the result

Comment: `SELECT sales_product.reciept_no,sum(price) AS TotalPrice,sum(qty) AS TotalQuantity,username,date,customer.firstname,customer.lastname FROM sales_product JOIN sales ON sales_product.reciept_no=sales.reciept_no JOIN customer ON sales.customer_id = customer.customer_id GROUP BY reciept_no ( AND reciept_no LIKE "%%" OR TotalPrice LIKE "%%" OR TotalQuantity LIKE "%%" OR username LIKE "%%" OR firstname LIKE "%%" OR lastname LIKE "%%") ORDER BY reciept_no DESC LIMIT0,5` . This is what comes out

Comment: check my answer, you are using GROUP BY before LIKE, ORDER BY LIMIT

Comment: okay tnx. I'll try to debug the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188995/discussion-between-devpro-and-roncajan).

Comment: getting success or not?

Comment: Cant fecth the data. I message you on the chat box. @devpro

Comment: replied on chat, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your `json` response, you have an issue in your query:

```
{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":10,"recordsFiltered":null,"data":[]}
```

`recordsFiltered == null` means `$query` have an issue.

***What is the issue:***

You are concatenating your query, you are using `GROUP BY` here:

```
$query = "SELECT sales_product.reciept_no,sum(price) AS TotalPrice,sum(qty) AS TotalQuantity,username,date,customer.firstname,customer.lastname FROM sales_product JOIN sales ON sales_product.reciept_no=sales.reciept_no JOIN customer ON sales.customer_id = customer.customer_id GROUP BY reciept_no";
```

But after this you have few condition in `$_POST` and you are concatenating the queries like this, which will not work anymore:

```
SELECT
FROM
JOIN
GROUP
LIKE >>> here is the issue
```

You must need to save `GROUP` part in an another variable as you are concatenating, and put it them at last part of your query, something like:

```
$query .= " GROUP BY reciept_no "; // use this after LIKE clauses.
```

***More clarification:***

> you have this method `get_all_data` which you giving you `10 records`
>   in json response, where you dont have any WHERE and LIKE clause.

In simple words, you are using `GROUP BY` before `LIKE` , `LIMIT` , your last comment explain each and everything.

***From your comment:***

```
SELECT sales_product.reciept_no,sum(price) AS TotalPrice,sum(qty) AS TotalQuantity,username,date,customer.firstname,customer.lastname 
FROM sales_product 
JOIN sales ON sales_product.reciept_no=sales.reciept_no 
JOIN customer ON sales.customer_id = customer.customer_id 
GROUP BY reciept_no // here is the issue
( AND reciept_no LIKE "%%" OR TotalPrice LIKE "%%" OR TotalQuantity LIKE "%%" OR username LIKE "%%" OR firstname LIKE "%%" OR lastname LIKE "%%") 
ORDER BY reciept_no DESC 
LIMIT0,5 // this will also create an issue, you must need space between LIMIT and 0
```

***Few more suggestion:***

In this method `get_all_data()` you just need to get number of rows, so no need to `SELECT` all columns and `SUM` method, you just need to select `reciept_no` column for `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Yeah, I understand it now. So the problem is in my query.

Comment: @RonCajan: i have updated a solution `$query .= " GROUP BY reciept_no "; // use this after LIKE clauses.`

Answer (score 0):

Replace this, it should work.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $sub_array = array();
    $sub_array['reciept_no'] = $row["reciept_no"];
    $sub_array['username'] = $row["username"];
    $sub_array['firstname'] = $row["firstname"];
    $sub_array['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
    $sub_array['TotalQuantity'] = $row["TotalQuantity"];
    $sub_array['TotalPrice'] = $row["TotalPrice"];
    $sub_array['date'] = $row["date"];
    $data[] = $sub_array; 
}
```

Comment: I'd tried but same error happen. I did search the problem, I found this error **Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PointOfSale/sales/fetch_all_data.php on line 38

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PointOfSale/sales/fetch_all_data.php on line 40
{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":10,"recordsFiltered":null,"data":[]}**

Comment: try echo 1 instead of that, I means, you need to debug until that step comes ie my running code

Comment: I'd put the error on my comment on this answer. The bold one

Comment: @RahulMeshram: OP have an issue with query... using GROUP BY before LIMIT and ORDER BY :) chk my answer